# How to remove Non-numeric characters

Tags: vba, excel

I want to remove *Rs.* sign from the excel using VBA

> Rs. 32,899.00  |   34,272.00

These are the values in my cell,

I want to remove *Rs.* using VBA, because in my excel I am subtracting (34,272 - 32,899)

Please help me

Comment: [This Link](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-substring-function/) might help.

Comment: I tried this in VBA " Right("Rs. 32,899.00", 3) " but it isn't working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Macro record button?

Try this to remove "Rs." from all cells in the Worksheet:

```
 Cells.Replace What:="Rs.", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
            :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Try this to remove "Rs. " from the beginning of a number in VBA:

```
CDbl(Right(rng, Len(rng)-Len("Rs. "))
```

Comment: Sorry ,Didn't get you .I am new to VBA

Comment: This macro will remove all "Rs." from your worksheet before you execute the macro. Alternatively CDbl(Right(rng, Len(rng)-4) in VBA

Comment: Osum @Analystcave.com dude it worked,Thank u so much and whoever has downvoted it ,Y did u do so?

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer then. No not me the downvote.

Comment: It is not showing to mark the Answer correct ,Its just showing as a comment.